# How to make jQuery slider work for generated IDs?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, carousel, slideshow

I have created auto generated ids such as

> gallary-item-0, gallery-item-1, gallery-item-1

and so on with PHP. How to configure `jQuery` to start a slider for each id.
Here is the code I wrote but it works only for the first ID.

```
var i = 0;
sleepTime = setInterval(function () {
    var id = $(this).attr("id");           
    $('#gallery-item-'+i).ionImageSlider({
         slideWidth: 150,
         minSlides: 2,
         maxSlides: 10,
         moveSlides: 1,
         slideMargin: 50,
         pager: false
    });
    i++; 
    clearInterval(sleepTime);
}, 3000);
});
```

Comment: The last `});` is not matched. Is that an error through copy and paste?

Comment: I don't know how ionImageSlider is working but you can try to use an [attribute selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) for instanciating the silder: `$('[id^="gallery-item-").ionImageSlider()`

Comment: Try `setTimeout` rather than setInterval/clearInterval inside the interval

Comment: It only works for the first one because you clear the timer during the first one, so it never gets called with `i>0`

Answer (score 0):

Don't call `clearInterval(sleepTime)` where you are calling it, because it will only fire once, like `setTimeout`.

Create a variable that has the count of all items with an id starting with `gallery-item`, and then call `clearInterval` in your handler when the count is reached.

```
var i = 0, 
total = $('[id^="gallery-item-"]').length,
sleepTime = setInterval(function () {
    $('#gallery-item-'+ i).ionImageSlider({
         slideWidth: 150,
         minSlides: 2,
         maxSlides: 10,
         moveSlides: 1,
         slideMargin: 50,
         pager: false
    });
    i++; 
    if (i == total - 1) {
        clearInterval(sleepTime);
    }     
}, 3000);
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what you are intending to use the timer for - show all after 3 seconds, or show each one after 3 seconds.

Without a timer:

```
for (var i=0;i<2;++i) {
    $('#gallery-item-'+i).ionImageSlider({
         slideWidth: 150,
         minSlides: 2,
         maxSlides: 10,
         moveSlides: 1,
         slideMargin: 50,
         pager: false
    });
}
```

With a single timer:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    ... same code as above ...
}, 3000);
```

With mutliple timers:

```
for (var i=0;i<2;++i) {
    var loopI = i;
    setTimeout(function() {
        $('#gallery-item-'+loopI).ionImageSlider({
             slideWidth: 150,
             minSlides: 2,
             maxSlides: 10,
             moveSlides: 1,
             slideMargin: 50,
             pager: false
        });
    }, 3000 + (i+1));
}
```

You can get the max items (The `2` in the code above) from your php or using a selector as in the comments.

Comment: Thanks a lot . The first code help a lot. Now I have as much sliders as ID-s I have, but the images from separate ID-s (div ID-s) are shown in the first slide i.e. #gallery-item-0. Below the code how to generate img structure:      $('.gallery-item img').each(function () {
     var src = $(this).attr("src");
        var bigSrc = src.replace("-150x150","");
       $(this).wrap("<a href='" + bigSrc + "'></a>");
    });

Comment: Issue is likely due to closures. Check SO for more info.  Third code here handles it.  Most likely your i var is global.

Comment: p.s. The div has also class name as  .gallery-item

Comment: What do you mean SO?